# WPF ObservableCollection two way binding XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I want to bind an `ObservableCollection` to an XML file.  Before the multiple replies of

> You should bind your `DataGrid`, `ComboBox`, etc.. directly to the XML file

Please note that the `ObservableCollection` already exists and is already being bound to `DataGrid`, `ComboBox` etc...  Re-writing all that code doesn't sound like fun at all to me.  Although every search I do about binding an XML file to a `ObservableCollection` returns binding object directly the XML file.

Yes I know I could manually do the add, update, and delete myself but was hoping to not have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> manually do the add, update, and delete myself

Please don't delete yourself. ;-)

Xml node processing is a complex process and does not easily lend itself to such a scenario as adding and deleting from a string list which is what the question is patterning itself off of....

At some point code is needed as a go between, the visual and storage, to facilitate the process of managing the xml structure as adds and deletes are done.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Blend has support for binding straight to XML. Perhaps you could add some design time data to the form in Blend, and see what it generates. It might give you some ideas.

Comment: Interesting option actually.